# Google Sheets/Excel Web Scraping - Variable page count into Link URL

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

If there's an easier way to do this please lmk, but this is what I have so far.

```
=importhtml("https://example/101", "list", 4)
```

There are 100 items per page, so if this is in A1, would like something like this:

```
=importhtml("https://example/201", "list", 4)
```

to go into A101 (or B1 and then change to single column later)

... and so on so the last part of the url keeps getting incremented by 100 each time.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
={IMPORTHTML("https://example/101", "list", 4)
  IMPORTHTML("https://example/201", "list", 4)}
```